# Question about hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

The hyphenation of this sentence is throwing me off, and I want to make sure I have them in the right place. Here's the sentence:

> Each member of our team is mid- to senior-level.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the "suspended hyphen"!  The 'Mayfield Electronic Handbook of Technical & Scientific Writing' nicely describes the use of this punctuation:

..If all unit modifiers in a series end with the same term, the term does not have to be repeated each time; for brevity you may suspend the hyphens and use the modified term only at the end of the series.

..... The first-, second-, and third-order equations have all been solved.
[or]
..... 2- and 3-phase controllers

An electronic version of that handbook is on MIT's website at:
http://www.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/hyphen.htm